# Inet6Address.getByName() giving odd response for 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:0:0

Tags: java, ipv6, ipv4

I'm using the following code to normalise IPv6 IP addresses:

```
try {
    return Inet6Address.getByName(ipAddress).getHostAddress();
} catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
    return ipAddress;
}
```

However, when I use IP "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:0:0", I get "0.0.0.0" as the response. I tried this code with "ffff" in each of the other octets, and they seem to be fine:

```
ffff:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
0:ffff:0:0:0:0:0:0
0:0:ffff:0:0:0:0:0
0:0:0:ffff:0:0:0:0
0:0:0:0:ffff:0:0:0
0.0.0.0
0:0:0:0:0:0:ffff:0
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:ffff
```

Any thoughts on why this IP in particular wouldn't return an IPv6 format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getHostAddress()` is (correctly) displaying an [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5.2).

Comment: Cheers, didn't even know that was part of the standard.